# Tagging: [How|Can] I install [Ubuntu|Android|Arch]?

Tags: discussion, tags

How should we tag these posts?

Currently, they are getting OS-specific tags and [operating-systems](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operating-systems) tag. A few had the [setup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/setup) tag, so I've added it to others, but I'm not sure this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

OS specific tags are good, as is the setup tag (I think this is good for any aspect of setting up the Pi.)

Not convinced on the operating-systems tag though - isn't this implied by the OS specific tag anyway? I say remove it.

Comment: The os tag allows you to find them all together.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain True, but I'd say looking for all OS specific questions is a very wide birth to have a tag, especially in the future when it's likely many more systems will be commonly available.

Comment: I think the [tag:operating-systems] tag should be used when the question involves **multiple** operating systems, such as OS selection - "What is the best OS for X application?".

Comment: @AlexL Is right. the OS tag was intended for questions where the OS was necessarily ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

The tags should be becoming self explanitory by now. If users are confused about what tags to use then I think we have a problem with our tag wikis which probably needs action.

We have OS specific tags [archlinux](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archlinux) and [debian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debian). We also have the more specific [setup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/setup). These should be enough for these questions.

Ask yourself what would make the question easiest to find, and what tag it would benefit from most.